# Rewrite URL for multiple languages using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a multi-language website and I'm having a little trouble with rewriting URLs.

I must have something like this:

```
1) mysite.com/en
2) mysite.com/en/product-one
3) mysite.com/en/product-one/id25/title-page-fake.html
4) mysite.com/en/login.php
```

the urls redirect to:

```
1) mysite.com/index.php
2) mysite.com/index.php
3) mysite.com/item.php?id=25
4) mysite.com/login.php
```

My .htaccess file currently looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+/{0,0})$ $1/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+/)(.*)$ $2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^id(\d+)\/.*$ item.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

works, but throws exceptions:

Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Are these rules working for you?

Comment: Then what is the problem :)

Comment: .htaccess rules cause infinite loop...

Comment: Well that means its not working right?

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess/

Comment: works, but throws exceptions: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Is there any other .htaccess anywhere in the system OR any other rule in current .htaccess?

Comment: there is nothing else ...

Comment: But your current rules don't make any sense. They just don't don't relate with your requirements.

Comment: I know ... but after several attempts it works, but I know not to be the right solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# requirements 1 & 2
RewriteRule ^en(/product-one)?/?$ /index.php [L,NC]

# requirement # 3
RewriteRule ^en/product-one/id([0-9]+) /item.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# requirement # 4
RewriteRule ^en/([^.]+\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Let me know if it works then I can suggest other rule also.

Comment: Yes for 3 & 4 I will provide my answer.