# .htaccess - One language in the root folder, and other in subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a website with 2 or more languages, that get changes based on URL with subfolders. I don't have much experience with `.htaccess` files.

This is the code i use inside `.htaccess` file placed in the `root` folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Multi lang version
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(en) index.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(en)/(.*)$ $2.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php  [L,NC]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. `sitename.com/` target `root/index.php`
2. `sitename.com/en` target `root/index.php`
3. `sitename.com/en/`target `root/index.php`
4. `sitename.com/pagename`target `root/pagename.php`
5. `sitename.com/pagename/`target `root/pagename.php`
6. `sitename.com/en/pagename` target `root/pagename.php`
7. `sitename.com/en/pagename/` target `root/pagename.php`
8. `sitename.com/404` target `root/error.php`
9. `sitename.com/404/` target `root/error.php`
10. `sitename.com/en/404` target `root/error.php`
11. `sitename.com/en/404/` target `root/error.php`

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439693/9208870) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19727555/9208870), but it doesn't work.

If go to `sitename.com/en` everything works. It load `index.php` file.
But when I go to `sitename.com/en/`brings me to `404` page. Same thing on `sitename.com/en/pagename/`.
And when I try to go to `sitename.com/fakelanguage/`brings me to `root/index.php` page, instead of `404` page.

There is a way to make all cases work?

Comment: This is an XY problem. You don't know how to do X, so you try Y. Y isn't working, so you ask about Y instead. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: What you really want is an internationalisation lib, then you only have one set of files to maintain, and to pass placeholders to a translate function with the language selected.

Comment: Try this library for example https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a couple of guides I found the solution to my problem.

This is my `.htaccess` code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Multi language version
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#EN
RewriteRule ^en/([^.]+)/?$ $1  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/([^.]+\.php)/?$ $1  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/?$ index.php  [L,NC]

#IT
RewriteRule ^it/([^.]+)/?$ $1  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^it/([^.]+\.php)/?$ $1  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^it/?$ index.php  [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php  [L,NC]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

It works great for all cases listed in the question:

- `sitename.com/pagename` target `root/pagename.php`
- `sitename.com/pagename/` target `root/pagename.php`
- `sitename.com/pagename.php` target `root/pagename.php`
- `sitename.com/en/pagename` target `root/pagename.php`
- `sitename.com/en/pagename/` target `root/pagename.php`
- `sitename.com/en/pagename.php` target `root/pagename.php`

and even this cases

- `sitename.com/pagename.php/` target `root/pagename.php`
- `sitename.com/en/pagename.php/` target `root/pagename.php`

And finally it bring me to page `404` when I go to `sitename.com/fakelanguage/`

Comment: I tried this and it seams to work fine when I use `domain/en' . The only problem I get is,  wenn I use `domain/en/`. At that point my css is not beeing loaded. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: I got this fixed by using absolute paths for images and stylesheets ect